# iOS geofences dwell event

Tags: ios, core-location, android-geofence

There is a dwell event for Android devices to detect user had  stopped moving and standing in region . But there is no event for iOS. Are there any idea how to catch this event ?

Comment: Perhaps just determine when they enter a region via `CLLocationManager`, then set a timer, and if you haven't gotten an "exited region" event by the time the timer goes off, the user is dwelling.  Not sure how well this would work when your app is in the background, but I'm sure it's possible. :)

Comment: the dwell time is about not triggering enter/exit events for a geofence.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you are looking for the Visit API.  Keep in mind, this only works with iOS 8+. Here is link about it: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLVisit_class/